# iOS: store userName, password and access token using keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I want to use keychain in order to store username, password and access token. I added the `keychainItem.h` and `keyChainItem.m` implemented [here](https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641). And this is what I did:

1- I created a property keychain in `myViewController.h` then in the `viewDidLoad` I instantiate it like this:

```
self.keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Login" accessGroup:nil];
```

When I got the userName, password and the access token this is what I did:

2- To store the userName

```
[self.keychain setObject:userName forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

When I test it, it works.

Now I want to add the password and the access token.

For the access token I tried

```
[self.keychain setObject:accessToken forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];
```

When I run it the application crash:

```
Assertion failure in -[KeychainItemWrapper writeToKeychain] KeychainItemWrapper.m:322
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't update the Keychain Item.'
```

I tried to create another keychain

```
self.keychainToken = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@“Token” accessGroup:nil];
```

then I set the value:

```
[self.keychainToken setObject:accessToken forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
```

But I got the same error.

What is wrong with what I did? How can I store the user, password and the accessToken using keychain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
self.keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Login" accessGroup:nil];

[self.keychain setObject:userName forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[self.keychain setObject:password forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
[self.keychain setObject:accessToken forKey:(id)kSecAttrTokenID];
[self.keychain setObject:@"LoginService" forKey: (id)kSecAttrService];
```

Comment: And what about the password?

Comment: When I use kSecValueData for the accessToken it works you're right. But how can I store the password?

Comment: Sorry but the application crash with the same message

Comment: My bad. `kSecValueData` only store string value. I have updated the answer. Try it and let me know.

Comment: It woooorks thank you! Can you tell me please is kSecAttrService required or optional? What is it role? And if I want to store an NSDictionnary is that possible with something else than kSecValueData?  Thaaaank again and sorry for all those questions

Comment: `NSDictionnary` is not possible. All keys are `CFStringRef` type in case of `KeychainItemWrapper`. There number of keys available. Just click on any of the keys and it will take you to `SecItem.h` of `Security` framework where all others keys are defined. And remove `kSecAttrService` and check if woks or not.

Comment: Thank you. It works without kSecAttrService. For the NSDictionnary, in your opinion, is it a good solution to use something like the answers in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948698/store-nsdictionary-in-keychain . Or ideal is to use the keychain only for string because this is the goal of it (store password..)?

Comment: If you want to store only password and username then my code does the job but if you want to store lots of info then use according to the mentioned link.